# Linear Vec search vs HashMap get in rust

Tags: data-structures, rust

Given a key-value problem, storing data in a HashMap is the most natural fit and leads to less comparisons.

However, what conditions might just saving the data on a Vec, doing a linear search/match perform better? Thinking about cost of computing the hash.

Comment: None. Searching unsorted vector is `O(n)` and calculating hash and doing a hash lookup is roughly constant.

Comment: The only concrete way to tell is to measure.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of elements is very small, and the keys are long (making the hash expensive) and key comparisons can mostly be decided quickly (because most keys have differences in their first bytes), then a `Vec` *may* be faster.

I did a benchmark in C a few years back in which a GLib `GPtrArray` was faster than a `GHashTable` up to around 100 elements. But note that in that same benchmark, a custom implementation of a Robin-Hood hash table had performances similar to the `GPtrArray` for small sizes (and of course the RH hash table had much better performance for larger datasets).

As always for performance questions, benchmark yourself in your environment and with your workload.